# Storing website files in /usr/share/www/ instead of /var/www/

Tags: server, directory, webserver, webapps

I have just [seen](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/dirstructure.html) the `/var/` directory being defined as:

```
Multi-purpose log, temporary, transient, and spool files. A memory-based file system is sometimes mounted at /var.
```

Whereas `/usr/` has been described as:

```
The majority of user utilities and applications.
```

and `/usr/share/` is:

```
Architecture-independent files.
```

To my eye, it looks like web apps I write fall under "user utilities and applications" (but this is a server, so storing this stuff under my home directory is impractical if I want other admins to work on it). My web apps have nothing to do with the 'system architecture'.

Hence, `/usr/share/www/` looks like a great place to store web apps and serve from, as opposed to `/var/www/`. I am aware apache server's convention is to store in `/var/`, but I'm using a different server and even if I was using apache, I don't mind stepping on this particular convention's toes.

My question is, any compelling arguments against using this directory?

Comment: You might also want to read the manual page `hier(7)`. FWITW, on my server I use a separate partition mounted on `/www/` instead of `/var/www/`.

Comment: Oh, that is a pretty awesome man page @Lekensteyn, thanks for pointing out! `/usr/local/` seems to have many conventions already set up for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah, `/www/` (separately mounted if possible) seems like the very best option...

Comment: I was also suggested that `/opt/` is a good candidate, and the description on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem) for this directory sounds great as well! Ah... so many choices :)

Comment: I think you are reading too much into those description of the linux file system. at any rate, you may configure your web server to use any directory you wish. /var/www/ is the default, but config as you wish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing forcing you to use either. You can define where you want your files to live. Some people move them under their user accounts, some people create a `/srv/` directory... I've created a `/websites/` directory.

`/var/www/` is just a convention. You don't have to follow it.

**Edit**: [`/srv/` is actually a convention too](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM), just not one Debian/Ubuntu follows currently.